# OperationalError: index teckno_thematique_ad621c37 already exists

Tags: django, migrate, makemigrations

I tried to migrate but I got an error.

I did :

```
python ./manage.py makemigrations teckno
```

and

```
 python ./manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: index teckno_thematique_ad621c37
>   already exists

Answer (score 0):

this error is just telling you that the migration that you're running is trying to recreate an index on the teckno.thematique field. if you already ran the migration or part of a migration and it was left in place, you might want to either go back to a previous migration or delete the index yourself via the database directly.